# Is there any reason to help the civilians in need?

Tags: the-division

While walking around the city, you'll sometimes encounter citizens in need. ISAC will scan them for you and identify which consumable you can give them. So far, this only results in you getting an extremely minor amount of experience points - seemingly less than 1% of a level for me. What is the benefit of helping these guys?

Comment: To feel good knowing you're giving back to the community?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main reason to help civilians in need is for the XP and for the items they drop. At least in the beta, the item was typically a cosmetic item but I've heard they can drop weapon skins as well.

Everything I've read about leveling up quickly has said to help the civilians in need for the XP. So I'd say the main reason to help them is for the XP.

I kept track of how much XP Civilians in Need gave me today, and this is what I found:

- At level 6, 209 XP
- At level 7, 213 XP
- At level 8, 219 XP

(Note that I have already unlocked the +10% XP perk, so these numbers include that bonus.)

This means as you increase in level, so does the amount of XP they give. Of course, at lower levels this will still be a higher percentage of the amount of XP you need to get to the next level, but they definitely aren't worthless (IMO) as you progress through the game.

Comment: I have not played the game yet (at work/game is shipping and avoided the beta) but I would assume this is more effective at lower levels and is less and less effective the further you get, which could be what OP is experiencing. Unless the XP they give scales evenly with your level?

Comment: @DangerZone I haven't come across any civilians in need since the game was released yesterday. I'll try to make a note of how much XP I get for helping them and my level, and see if the amount increases or stays the same.

Comment: I played last night and ran into a couple civilians. In early levels (1-5), I seemed to be getting around 130-ish (at least from what I remember). And I'm always full on supplies anyway so I don't see a reason to not give them stuff. Plus I was getting cosmetic items like half the time. Not too shabby.

Comment: In my experience, I've only ever gotten vanity items from them or in the rare case, a consumable. I don't remember ever getting mods from them.

Comment: @DangerZone I updated my answer to show that the amount of XP you get from Civilians in Need does increase as you level up.

Comment: Awesome! So they don't scale evenly... Still worth taking advantage of though!

Comment: @DangerZone Yep, I agree. I'm also nearly always full on consumables, so no reason to not stop and get some XP for my efforts.

Comment: I'm accepting it since this seems to be the best answer, but by level 10 the experience you get for helping one still seems to be 200 base. That's a pittance. Aside from that this answer is dead on - you can earn cosmetic stuff (finally had it happen for me earlier) and you tend to have a decent number of spare consumables.

Comment: In the Beta I definitely got a weapon skin from one. Still cosmetic, but rare.

Comment: As I progress in levels (almost 20 now), cosmetic stuff seems to be an almost 100% reward from helping civilians in need. Still no weapon skins, but my clothing collection is rapidly expanding. EXP from this is basically pointless past the first few levels.

Comment: On few rare occasions I got weapons and mods, gray tier, so total crap. But 99% it's clothes.